# Multiple maximum labelling matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to label multiple maximum but unable to display them properly. Also the label is appearing too far from the point overlapping with the legend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1,y1= np.loadtxt('MaxMin1.txt', dtype=str, unpack=True)

x1 = x1.astype(int)
y1 = y1.astype(float)

x2,y2= np.loadtxt('MaxMin2.txt', dtype=str, unpack=True)

x2 = x2.astype(int)
y2 = y2.astype(float)

x3,y3= np.loadtxt('MaxMin3.txt', dtype=str, unpack=True)

x3 = x3.astype(int)
y3 = y3.astype(float)

#-------------------------------------------------------------
def annot_max(x,y, ax=None):
    xmax = x[np.argmax(y)]
    ymax = y.max()
    text= "x={:.3f}, y={:.3f}".format(xmax, ymax)
    if not ax:
        ax=plt.gca()
    bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",connectionstyle="angle,angleA=0,angleB=60")
    kw = dict(xycoords='data',textcoords="axes fraction",
              arrowprops=arrowprops, bbox=bbox_props, ha="left", va="top")
    ax.annotate(text, xy=(xmax, ymax), xytext=(0.94,0.96), **kw)


#-------------------------------------------------------------

fig=plt.figure()
fig.show()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x1,y1,c='b',ls='-',label='Recovery',fillstyle='none')
ax.plot(x2,y2,c='g',ls='-',label='Normal')
ax.plot(x3,y3,c='r',ls='-',label='No-Recovery')
annot_max(x1,y1)
annot_max(x2,y2)
annot_max(x3,y3)
plt.legend(loc=1)

# naming the x axis 
plt.xlabel('<------Instances(count)------>') 
# naming the y axis 
plt.ylabel('Acceleration (m/sq.sec)') 
# giving a title to my graph 
plt.title('Fall Detection Comparison graph')

plt.show()
```

And the output I got [Output Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H8IpJ.jpg)
I am just beginning with python so very small hint may not be understandable by me.Please help.

Comment: I would use `textcoords="offset points"` and `xytext=(25,12)`. Of course you can play around with the values to see what fits.

Comment: Will give it a try and update result here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need yo change function `annot_max`. 
First of all, all your labels appear in the same place according to `xytext=(0.94,0.96)`. You have to specify label position according to coordinates of xmax and ymax as below.

Then change `textcoords` to `data` value to manipulate a label position according to data not axes fraction. In my example `xytext=(xmax+.5,ymax+5)` means that location of label box will shifted by +.5 point from xmax and +5 points by ymax (you have to use your own values according to your data).

But I recommend to place your labels manually since you have 3 maximum (specify a location of every label box in argument `xytext` like `xytext=(100,40)` - your 1st maximum).

Matplotlib can not avoid overlapping of text boxes automatically.

To squeeze label box you can place text in two rows, i.e., `text= "x={:.3f},\ny={:.3f}".format(xmax, ymax)`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x1=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
x2 = x1[:]
x3 = x1[:]
y1=np.array([1,2,3,100,5,6,7,8,9,10])
y2=np.array([50,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
y3=np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,75,8,9,10])

#-------------------------------------------------------------
def annot_max(x,y, ax=None):
    xmax = x[np.argmax(y)]
    ymax = y.max()
    text= "x={:.3f}, y={:.3f}".format(xmax, ymax)
    if not ax:
        ax=plt.gca()
    bbox_props = dict(boxstyle="square,pad=0.3", fc="w", ec="k", lw=0.72)
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="->",connectionstyle="angle,angleA=0,angleB=60")
    kw = dict(xycoords='data',textcoords="data",
              arrowprops=arrowprops, bbox=bbox_props, ha="left", va="top")
    ax.annotate(text, xy=(xmax, ymax), xytext=(xmax+.5,ymax+5), **kw)


#-------------------------------------------------------------

fig=plt.figure()
fig.show()
ax=fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(x1,y1,c='b',ls='-',label='Recovery',fillstyle='none')
ax.plot(x2,y2,c='g',ls='-',label='Normal')
ax.plot(x3,y3,c='r',ls='-',label='No-Recovery')
annot_max(x1,y1)
annot_max(x2,y2)
annot_max(x3,y3)
plt.legend(loc=1)

# naming the x axis 
plt.xlabel('<------Instances(count)------>') 
# naming the y axis 
plt.ylabel('Acceleration (m/sq.sec)') 
# giving a title to my graph 
plt.title('Fall Detection Comparison graph')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So the only change I see is xytext=(xmax+.5,ymax+5). However when I am running this the max labels go out of the visibility area. I am sharing the data files if that helps, in my OP.

Comment: No, change  `textcoords="data"` in `arrowprops`.

Comment: you made a misprint. Take my code, load your data and change `xytext` position as your desire.